# How SharePoint add-ins can identify the Host Site URL?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

How my add-ins(Provider hosted) can know Host site URL where it is running?

Actually, In my case there are external and internal farm with different site URL (see below 2 URLs). Now, in my app, How to get the host site URL? There is single code which runs for both add-ins (external and internal).

e.g

External site: https://external.mycompany.com/sites/0028

Internal site: https://internal.mycompany.com/sites/0029

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have the code so you should have client id for both the apps. To check the host URL you can simply append **"/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx"** to the site URL. For Example in your case it should be :

External site: https://external.mycompany.com/sites/0028/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx

Internal site: https://internal.mycompany.com/sites/0029/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx

On the page you can enter the client id  and search, it will show you all the details related to app.

Comment: thx for reply. Yes, I already have Client ID in hand. My quest was - how my app when it runs, will know its Host URL?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it with `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`